# Remove white from image on css

Tags: html, css

How i can remove white with filters on image?

For example:

[image: Sample image]

Comment: You need to edit the image. There is no way that I know of to filter out a single color from an image using CSS.
Try creating a PHP file that will use the GD library to filter out the white and replace it with a transparent color or something to that effect.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<div style="background-image:url(http://images.huffingtonpost.com/2015-06-24-1435146764-7694757-lovable_bear2.jpg); background-blend-mode: darken;"></div>
```

This way it`s true!!!!

Comment: the image has to support transparency for that to actually result in anything. JPG do not.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with photoshop. You have to use quick selection (keyword W) and select the image, then open into a new one and at the end you have to add the background